# Rendering and jaggering

Tags: javascript

I have a html 5 canvas using the 2d context. I am able to get up to 120 frames per second, but the rendering can be jagged, where the animation just jumps. I would like to know any ideas what may be causing it, especially with such a high (but pointless) frame rate? What are known ways or smoothing out animation as well?

The only thing that does come to mind, is the actual drawing is not being accounted for. So while the updating and drawing functions can be run quickly, the painting onto the canvas is stacked later. Which would then imply that I am not geting a true frames per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, I can get 120 frames per seconds that really means nothing. Because I am using `setTimeout`, I have not guarantees that the time will be constant, thus, when it does jagger, that is because the frame rate, for a moment, has dropped significantly.

However, there is an alternative in the works, that I managed to found. I'm a bit surprised how hard this was to find.

http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/requestanimationframe-implementation

From what I can understand, the function allows the browser to optimise for animations. In theory, this should give a more consistent frame rate, which should give smoother animations.

It is also quite interesting to compare how Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox draw. I mainly test on Chrome 14 dev and Mozilla Aurora 6.0a, and they way draw look very different. Chrome seems to be able to draw directly. Firefox seems to be piping the pixels, as if it's sending them one by one to be drawn.

Which leads me to Opera

http://www.scribd.com/doc/58835981/122/Double-Buffering-with-Canvas
http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2010/09/accelerated-game-programming-with-html5-and-canvas/

turns out Webkit-based browsers and Gecko-based browsers use double buffers internally, that is, it collects all the drawing functions together and then draws them on the return of the function thread. If you have a main loop function, like `update`, it won't draw until that has returned. Opera, just draws them as the drawing functions are called, but it's not hard to implement double buffering. This is, supposably, another method of smoothing out the animation.

There is also another experimental feature that may help as well

http://badassjs.com/post/4064873160/webgl-2d-an-implementation-of-the-2d-canvas-context-in